# Entity Framework - Add entity with existing dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I m trying to develop an asp net based server that use mssql and entity framework.
I ve 3 entity models
Model A{
[Key]
Int I’d
…

[foreign key]
Model B
[foreign key]
Model C
}
By the api controller I m able to post a modelA object (brand new) that contain existing model B and C object.

When I try to add entity model A
(Context.modelA.Add(entityA)
I ve got sql exception caused by
IDENTITY_INSERT OFF for model B and C entities.
Seems like ef try to save entities the are already stored into db.

I think that this problem can be solved using sqlraw but I hope that exist a code solution

Comment: seem that you try to add an element with ID in an autoincrement table, be sure that your new element had its ID set to null.

Comment: Thanks Romy, as you said, i've two object B and C with "autoincrement identity" but i would like to save a brand new entity A (without id) that contains B and C that are already stored. This is the exception: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'B' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF, Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'C' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Comment: It seems like EF try to save new  entities B and C that are foreign key in entity A insted of set a relation between A and B and A and C. I hope it is understandable

Comment: ok, I got you. So are you sure that your id exists in B and C. Also can you share the concerning code to see what goes wrong with it.

Comment: How about use sqlconnection?

Comment: show your [mcve]. It could be that you de-attached tracking of object B and C. It they're not tracked, EF doen't know hey're in the database already, and EF will try to add them again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't post the model A and add directly. Instead you should make a new input model. You can try the following sample to tell the difference.
Student.cs

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        public int ClassId { get; set; }
        public Class Class { get; set; }

    }
```

Class.cs

```
    public class Class
    {
        public int ClassId { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

MyContext.cs

```
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=192.168.2.68;database=WA117;user=mysql1;password=xxxxx", new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()));
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                        .HasOne(e => e.Class)
                        .WithMany(d => d.Students)
                        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ClassId);
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    }
```

program.cs  //the second line to avoid loop error.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

Controller

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public ValuesController(MyDbContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IEnumerable<Student> AddNew(string studentName, string className)
        { 
            int findclassid = _context.Classes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ClassName == className).ClassId;
            _context.Students.Add(new Student { StudentName = studentName,ClassId=findclassid });
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return _context.Students;
        }
    }
```

I already have "classA" and "classB" in the database. Now try add a student name "Terry" to "classB"
[image]
Result
[image]